# wordpress media query issues

Tags: css

I have a different header I want to do for different screensizes. I am having trouble getting the `@media` queries working or understanding them. Right now I have a slogan hard coded. For the wide screens I have the image bigger. And smaller another one. I cannot get the small image to go away on the wide screen.

Here are my media queries

- `@media only screen and ( min-width: 768px ) and ( max-width: 960px )`
- `@media only screen and ( max-width: 960px )`
- `@media only screen and ( max-width: 767px )`

`@media only screen and ( max-width: 479px ) {
        #slogan{
              display: none !important;
        }
        #slogan2 {
              float: none;
              background: url (http://www.wpcreations.net/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/mobile_logo.gif) no-repeat !important;
        }
    }`

For the smaller screen I have the the slogan `<div>` show but I think for other width it should not show but maybe . Please use Firefox and make screen bigger and smaller to see the issues and how can I hide the big image and then show the little or the other way around.

Comment: Please clean up your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you put the code to hide the smaller slogan inside the min-width: 768 AND max-width: 960. By default, the slogan div will have a display attribute of "block". Since you only give it a display of "none" between 768px and 960px, on larger screens it shows. Move the `#slogan { display: none; }` code above all your other media queries just have it as a normal CSS declaration and should fix it.